# php within php using bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Basically what I'm requesting to output isn't showing, I've got a navbar written in php, so that if a user is logged in, it shows different options, than if they weren't logged in. However upon adding this to my website, it's now interfering with other php.

Here's the code I'm using to output the php,

```
$envelope = '

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

         <li class="dropdown pull-right" id="menu1">
         <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu2">
          <i style="font-size: 20px; margin-right:5px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user Default"></i>
         </a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu" id="menu">
            <div id="friendReqBox"><p style="font-size:20px; text-decoration:bold;">Friend Requests</p><hr/> <?php echo $friend_requests; ?> </div>
         </div>
         </li>
        </ul>

    ';
```

Notice that within `" $envelope = ' ';` tag there's `echo $friend_requests;` wrapped within php tags, now I tried removing the php tags, but then it just outputs plaintext.

There is more php code to this, it's not just $envelope & there is php tags surrounding it, before you state I need them `>.<`, only reason I posted this was because the problem is within `$envelope = ' '`, now I can see what the problem is, I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: you're already in PHP, so why have `<?php echo`? error reporting should have thrown you an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a string, you don't ever need to run PHP inside that string. It will be evaluated when you return it to the browser (*example: printing or echoing it*)

```
$envelope = '

<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

     <li class="dropdown pull-right" id="menu1">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu2">
      <i style="font-size: 20px; margin-right:5px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user Default"></i>
     </a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" id="menu">
        <div id="friendReqBox"><p style="font-size:20px; text-decoration:bold;">Friend Requests</p><hr/> ' .$friend_requests . ' </div>
     </div>
     </li>
    </ul>

';
```

---

So what you're doing is essentially concatenating the string and adding the `$friend_requests` to the `$envelope` variable. Without the HTML, this is simple what it is:

```
$var1 = "Something";
$var2 = 'I like to do ' . $var1 . 'occasionally';
// which prints: I like to do Something occasionally
```

Comment: Edited: Found the issue, what you suggested worked perfectly, but I also had an issue within other code! Thanks for your response, really appreciated, I've been lost for hours >.<

Answer (score 0):

Your code should like this...

```
$envelope = '

<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

     <li class="dropdown pull-right" id="menu1">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu2">
      <i style="font-size: 20px; margin-right:5px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user Default"></i>
     </a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" id="menu">
        <div id="friendReqBox"><p style="font-size:20px; text-decoration:bold;">Friend Requests</p><hr/>' . $friend_requests . '</div>
     </div>
     </li>
    </ul>

';
```